# Run external javascript file on load

Tags: javascript, html

We made a website through webnode.nl, because we hadn't enough time to make a website using html. Now we added a widget using a external site using a script tag with the link to this site. But through this widget the page is loading slow. Now I had the idea to run the script after the page is loaded. But I can't access the code of the widget and I can't access the html of the website. I can only access the code block in which I pasted the script tag.

The script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mycountdown.org/countdown.php?cp2_Hex=d21a1a&cp1_Hex=F9F9FF&img=-3&hbg=&fwdt=420&lab=1&ocd=My Countdown&text1=Valentijnsdag!&text2=valentijnsdag!&group=My Countdown&countdown=My Countdown&widget_number=3015&event_time=1455408000&timezone=Europe/Amsterdam"></script>
```

Can someone help me?

PS: English is not my first language, so I don't know if my English is correct

Comment: add the script tag at the end of the `<body>`, just before closing the `<body>`.

Comment: I can't acces the whole html. Only the litle code block in which I can add html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can write script blocks then write the following in whatever you are allowed to use.

```html
<script>
  // Create a <script ...></script> element
  var widget = document.createElement('script');

  // Set src="URL_of_widget"
  widget.setAttribute('src', 'http://mycountdown.org/countdown.php?cp2_Hex=d21a1a&cp1_Hex=F9F9FF&img=-3&hbg=&fwdt=420&lab=1&ocd=My Countdown&text1=Valentijnsdag!&text2=valentijnsdag!&group=My Countdown&countdown=My Countdown&widget_number=3015&event_time=1455408000&timezone=Europe/Amsterdam');
  
  // Set async
  widget.setAttribute('async', 'async');

  // Insert <script> as the last element child of <body>
  document.body.appendChild(widget);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place it at the end of the `<body>` and add `async` to the script tag i.e.

```
<script async src=""></script>
```

More info here: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html There is also the defer attribute.

> Typically you want to use async where possible, then defer then no
>   attribute. Here are some general rules to follow: If the script is
>   modular and does not rely on any scripts then use async. If the script
>   relies upon or is relied upon by another script then use defer. If the
>   script is small and is relied upon by an async script then use an
>   inline script with no attributes placed above the async scripts.

**Edit**
You may be better using Defer:

> defer downloads the file during HTML parsing and will only execute it
>   after the parser has completed. defer scripts are also guarenteed to
>   execute in the order that they appear in the document.

Comment: It doesn't work. I added the defer atribute but now the script doesn't execute.

Comment: @tuin2121 which browser do you use? defer should work well

Comment: I am using Google Chrome